# Monkey-patch a npm module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, monkeypatching, es6-proxy

I have a module installed with npm with a single method as the default export. I have setup an ES6 Proxy with an `apply` handler to monkey-patch the method in the module. What I struggle with is how I can replace the module imports of the method, with the custom ES6 Proxy replacement.

I need the original module (let's call it `module A`) in the monkey-patch module where I create the proxy, so I can call the original method after I do the custom logic. Then everywhere else I want to import my proxied monkey-patched version (that is `module B`) instead of `module A`. But instead of having to change all imports in the codebase to import `B` instead of `A`, I would like to do it internally somehow in TypeScript.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered just forking the module and making your dependency be the forked version (npm will happily install packages from git commits)? This will allow you to build it as you wish, and contribute your changes back to the upstream package if they're widely useful.

Comment: Yes I have, but I really would like to do it the other way. I think it can be useful in even more situations where you need to implement middleware behavior. 